# Limited Area of a function

Tags: definite-integrals, area

What do they mean when they asked to calculate the above result again using the area? I knew the first part but I didn't understand
[image: part 2] what way I should use to solve part 2)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the integrand is the upper half of the unit circle. So you can calculate the integral by calculating the area of the quartercircle located in the first quadrant with area $\pi/4$, which should agree with your answer from part a.

Comment: Wowww!. How did you notice that! Nice one. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @AbedShaar $x^2+y^2=1\implies y^2=1-x^2\implies y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. It really is just noting patterns with lots of practice!